# Mongodb skips over check for duplicate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js

I'm using mongodb and next.js to check if a user exists in a database array, then add a like and increment a database element if this is true. The database is structured liked this:

> likes -> by -> [array of users]

[image]

My code to find if a user exists in the database array is this:

```js
 db.collection('quotes').findOne({
      likes: {
        by: cookies.get('user')
      }
    }, async function(liked) {
      if (!liked) {
      //...Add like
```

However, for some reason the like just keeps getting added, regardless of the check if the user exists. I also get this error for some reason:

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/like, this may result in stalled requests.

Here's my full code for `api/like`

```js
import clientPromise from "../../lib/mongodb";
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
import Cookies from 'cookies'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case 'POST': {
      return like(req, res);
    }
  }
}

async function like(req, res) {
  const cookies = new Cookies(req, res)
  const client = await clientPromise;
  const db = client.db("the-quotes-place");

  if (cookies.get('user') != null) {
    db.collection('quotes').findOne({
      likes: {
        by: cookies.get('user')
      }
    }, async function(liked) {
      if (!liked) {
        await db.collection('quotes').updateOne(
          { _id: new ObjectId(req.body.id) },
          {
          $inc: {
            "likes.num": 1
          },
          $push: {
            "likes.by": cookies.get('user')
          }
        })
        
        res.status(200).json({
          message: 'Succesfully added like',
          success: true
        })
      }
    })
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({
      message: 'Error: Cookies not found',
      success: true
    })
  }
}
```

What's going on here?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe use this query instead? `{ likes.by: cookies.get('user') }`

Comment: That's not valid syntax on it's own, and doing `{ "likes.by": cookies.get('user') }` does not solve it either.

Comment: What if you hard-code it for testing? `{ "likes.by": "jane" }`

Comment: It still increments unfortunately.

Comment: Also, if you are using async function then don't use a callback, use await: `let doc = await db.collection('quotes').findOne({ "likes.by": cookies.get('user') };`

Comment: Try running `db.collection('quotes').findOne({likes: {by: cookies.get('user')}})` via compass or mongo shell, then tweak it until it actually returns a document.